# Windows 10 taskbar pinned items exploring the exe folder instead launching the application

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts, pinning

I've upgraded my Windows-7_home_premium to windows-10_Home.

Everything looks fine, but the items pinned to the taskbar are opening the folder which contains the target app instead of launching the app.

E.g: When I click on the pinned chrome icon it does not launch the chrome but opens windows explorer in the folder where chrome.exe is installed.

The pinned items which target an exe file are behaving this way, but which target to a UWP-Based app (Not sure this is the correct word, I mean apps like Settings, Windows Store, Callender, etc.) are being launched as expected.

I tried un-pinning and re-pinning the apps but the behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

Go to “Control Panel\Hardware and Sound” and click “Mouse” and check your mouse settings;

For example look if left and right click are not interchanged: ensure that the left button is set to “Click” and right button is “Right-click”.

Comment: If you read the question how it is working for the apps from the windows store?
Will it not display the context menu?

BTW, mouse button are not interchanged.

Comment: Are you pinning shortcuts, or are you dragging them onto the taskbar?   I never had any resounding success upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10. You may wish to consider a fresh install of Windows 10 (Back up first). No licensing issues since Windows 10 is running.

Comment: I'm pinning items.